# Есть ли в rust рациональные числа (то есть обыкновенные дроби, не путать с числами с плавающей точкой)?

Tags: rust, числа, поиск-библиотек

Мне нужна библиотека в rust, предоставляющая действия с обыкновенными несократимыми дробями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека `num` выглядит норм. Доки: https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/rational/index.html